# Forcing unordered struct fields in C

Tags: c, optimization, data-structures, struct

I'm working on converter of object-oriented language into C for optimizing puproses and I've run into design issue.

Consider converter being provided with following class in pseudo-language:

```
class C {
    int a;
    double b;
    int c;

    constructor C(int value) {
        this.a = value;
        this.b = this.a / 10.0;
        this.c = 0;
    }

    void say() {
        print(this.b);
    }
}
```

When going straightforward, we can express this class in C as struct like that (skipping error checks):

```
typedef struct {
    int a;
    double b;
    int c;
} _class_C;

_class_C* _ctor_C(int value) {
    this = malloc(sizeof(_class_C));

    this->a = value;
    this->b = this->a / 10.0;
    this->c = 0;

    return this;
}

void _method_C_say(_class_C *this) {
    printf("%.2f", this->b);
}

void _dtor_C(_class_C *this) {
    free(this);
}
```

This solution suffers from the promise C compilers are bound with — do not add, remove or change order of fields in struct. So despite the fact fields `a` and `c` are not used, they will bloat the code.

**How can I achieve "unordered fields" behavior?** If I had only one static `C`, it could be written as follows:

```
int _staticfield_C_a;
double _staticfield_C_b;
int _staticfield_C_c;

void _ctor_C(int value) {
    _staticfield_C_a = value;
    _staticfield_C_b = _staticfield_C_a / 10.0;
    _staticfield_C_c = 0;
}

void _staticmethod_C_say() {
    printf("%.2f", _staticfield_C_b);
}
```

so compiler can optimize out redundant or unused fields up to sole `_staticfield_C_b`, but what solution should I use when `C` can be instantiated in dynamic, and I don't mind the order of fields, memory layout and code human-readability at all?

**Update:** It should be noted that I'm not trying to enforce compiler to do magic with *structs*, I want some *replacement* for them acting like struct with unordered field — much like that I've provided in static example, regardless of level of readablility.

**Update:** There is a popular opinion in the comments that my problem is related to design of converter itself, like if I chose wrong paradigm or language for it. Converter itself is written in Python, and it takes source of generic object-oriented program, processes it and outputs equivalent C code to be compiled, so you can think of it as cross-language compiler. I'm pleased with good intentions of explaining me where and how I should use structures, but in this case I need some help in magic to easen up optimization :)

Comment: Uh... how does the compiler/linker know that later on you won't link the object code it produces together with other (as yet unwritten) code that *does* access the "useless" fields? It doesn't know, so there is absolutely no question of removing them from the binary. Your only other option is to basically write a loose type system in its entirety.

Comment: Indeed it does not know, but *I do* know. This is rewritten code, it's never going to be linked against something not known at compile time. Due to your argumentation, there is no magic `--do-mess-with-structs` switch, but I want to trick compiler into doing things like I've described above. In fact, I don't even need structs themselves — some alternative to them, like in my "static" example, will be just perfect.

Comment: The best solution I can think of for this is to utilize hashmaps, but that would only work if you have classes with lots and lots of unutilized fields (economies of scale, so to speak), would likely be much slower than just using structs, and would mean you'd have to treat everything stored in it as a custom 'object' that you come up with. The other alternative would be to have a struct with two arrays/pointers (or possibly a 2D array), one holding an array of field names, the other pointing to the data; aside from the memory usage, however, the same disadvantages as the hashmap applies.

Comment: Besides your problem with unused fields. I am confused by your idea that constructors and destructors do the memory allocation by themselves. Shouldn't they receive a pointer to an existing object and operate on that?

Comment: @JAB, hashmaps are fine as idea, but as C does not have built-in support for them, and I will not reuse powers of nicely built symbol tables, control flow tracking etc., I will decrease perfomance with my own hashmap imlementation, so my main goal will be failed.

Comment: @JensGustedt, this is just sample. In fact I will get rid of malloc() in favor of preallocated pools of objects, as I have very large quantities of objects to be processed, and they have lots of redundant fields.

Comment: Don't write structs with fields you don't need?  "But how do I know that!?!" you say?  Well, with C your primary design pattern is composition.  (BTW, C doesn't have classes so even mentioning them is a suggestion that you might want to use a different tool or language).  I would recommend granularizing your structs so that they contain exactly what they need an nothing that they don't.  For example, struct IntPair{int a, int b};  You then use composition to combine these small pieces into a bigger piece (only putting in what you need and leaving out what you don't).

Comment: Followup to above:  Next, use data hiding and functional interfaces.  Define methods for what you want to do.  Define a method to produce a struct that allows you to do what you want to do.  You might have many different producers of structs that "do the same thing" but are optimized for the target.

Comment: I'm not using classes in C, and I'm not *writing* those structs — I'm implementing OOPL to C translator, so my goal is to give compiler easy, sparse, expanded, "chewed" source it can easily optimize.

Comment: @JoshPetitt, I'm working with foreign code, it's not mine :) I'm implementing translator, and the problem described in my question is related to representation of translated source, not to the source of translator itself.

Comment: @monchan, with the comments I have a better idea now what you want.  I would recommend looking at the Python implementation and how Python is compiled into byte code.  You could copy this for your language.  Or compile your language into Python! (which is then compiled into bytecode)

Comment: Can you define "unused fields"? Your constructor references them all so there is at least one function which ueses them. Can you elaborate a little bit?

Comment: I actually can't see the problem with leaving the fields there.  In your example, there is one unused field (c) and omitting that on ILP32 or LP64 architecture saves you exactly 4 bytes per instance and then possibly not if the compiler chooses to align memory allocations on 8 or 16 byte boundaries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to get the compiler (or linker -- the "remove unused objects" optimization you mention is actually done there) to automatically detect unused structure fields for you.  It can't, because it's impossible.  That's a global optimization -- you need to know that no code anywhere in the universe that references a given field.  But what if the code will bind dynamically to something in the future (code not part of the current link) that references that field?  What about compiling a library with the same header. How big should the compiler make the struct, given that it doesn't know how it will be used?

If you want to do this optimization, I'm afraid you'll have to do it yourself.  The C language doesn't have the tools available.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into `Unions` as an alternative to `Structs`?

If you're using only one field at a time and are worried about memory, this is the perfect data structure.

Comment: Unfortunately, as I work with foreign code, I don't know at compile time which fields are to be used, so this kind of optimization is up to compiler to decide.